# How can I implement the conversion between itk image and SimpleITK image in Python?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, itk

I know the way to implement the conversion between itk image and SimpleITK image in C++, which is an example in SimpleITK (Examples/ITKIntegration.cxx).

```
  //
  // Extract the itk image from the SimpleITK image
  //
  InternalImageType::Pointer itkImage =
    dynamic_cast <InternalImageType*>( image.GetITKBase() );
  ...
  //
  // Return to the simpleITK setting by making a SimpleITK image using the
  // output of the blur filter.
  //
  sitk::Image blurredImage = sitk::Image( blurFilter->GetOutput() );
```

But in Python, when I used "sitk.Image(itkImage)" in which itkImage is an itkImage, I got an error "this = _SimpleITK.new_Image(*args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Image'". And in python it's impossible to convert the type like "dynamic_cast" in C++.

There's one possible solution for this, which use PyBuffer to convert itkImage into numpy array and then use SimpleITK to convert array into SimpleITK image finally. But I fail in building the itkPyBuffer. And I think this method isn't direct to solve this problem.

Can you help me to convert the C++ code into available python code? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is the converter between ITK and SimpleITK image:
https://github.com/gregpost/itk-SimpleITK-Converter

Comment: Although it seems to be a valid answer, you should provide more information concerning how can this information provide an important solution for the question. Please try to improve your answer.

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference. Please note that this post may get deleted. How is it used? Show how it answers the Question.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate that a SimpleITK image cannot be instantiated in Python from an itk image. I didn't find a way around PyBuffer, so you might have to compile after all. Here is a description around a small bug that might help you: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MedPy/0.1.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have avoided to complile by copying all the files about itk from a software named DeVIDE(http://www.ohloh.net/p/DeVIDE) into the python itk directory, because itk in DeVIDE has "PyBuffer" and DeVIDE itself is easy to install. My solution sounds strange, but it works.